# Polymer 1.0 paper-drawer-panel call function when drawer closes

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I have a paper-drawer-panel that has a closed drawer. When I click a fab I open the drawer and hide the fab. However when the drawer closes again I would like to re-show the fab.

**My question is this: How do I know when the drawer is closing?**

I looked into the two events listed in the paper-drawer-panel docs and tried both paper-select and paper-responsive-change. I used them in the following way:

html:

```
<paper-drawer-panel right-drawer force-narrow narrow paper-select="changed">
  <div main> content... </div>
  <div drawer> drawer content </div>
</paper-drawer-panel>
```

js:

```
changed:function(){
  console.log("inside event");
}
```

should this work? can anyone offer some suggestions?

Comment: Try `iron-select`. See documentation in https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-drawer-panel/blob/v1.0.2/paper-drawer-panel.html

Comment: I solved this problem by changing paper-select to on-iron-select thanks @TrevorDixon

Comment: The `_isMainSelected` method of the `paper-drawer-panel` works too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment, I solved this by using TrevorDixon's advice and changing paper-select to on-iron-select

Answer (score 0):

http://jsbin.com/winedi/edit?html,output

```
menuToggle: function() {
        if (this.$.paper_drawer_panel.narrow && $(this.$.paper_drawer_panel).width() < parseInt(this.$.paper_drawer_panel.responsiveWidth)) {
            this.$.paper_drawer_panel.togglePanel();
        } else {
            this.$.paper_drawer_panel.forceNarrow = !this.$.paper_drawer_panel.forceNarrow;
        }
    }
```

took from [Polymer 1.0 paper-drawer-panel toggle is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30714253/polymer-1-0-paper-drawer-panel-toggle-is-not-working/31948434#31948434)